# Ajax request to send file from jsp to servlet

Tags: javascript, ajax, file, servlets, struts

Following is been done using struts framework

Jsp

```
<html:form action="/uploadDrawing" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="attachfile" class="regi_textbox"/>
<input type="submit" name="button" class="update_but"  value="Upload File" />
</html:form>
```

Form

```
private FormFile attachfile;

public FormFile getAttachfile() {
return attachfile;
}  
public void setAttachfile(FormFile attachfile) {
this.attachfile = attachfile;
}
```

Action class

```
FormFile attachfile = uploadDrawingForm.getAttachfile();
```

This works fine for me , but i need to do this using ajax request (jsp-servlet), following is what i tried with no success---

Jsp

```
 <script>
 function dynamicUpload()
 {  
alert("function played");
var fd = new FormData($("attachfileform"));    
fd.append( 'file', input.files[0] );


alert(fd);
$.ajax({
    url: 'UploadDrawingServlet',
    data: fd,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
      alert(data);

    }
});
}
 </script>

 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="" id="attachfileform" name="attachfileform" >
 <input type="file" name="attachfile" class="regi_textbox"/>
 <input type="button" class="update_but"  value="Upload File" onclick="dynamicUpload()"/>
  </form>
```

Servlet

```
public class UploadDrawingServlet extends HttpServlet{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String file = request.getParameter("data");

}   
}
```

For mapping in web.xml i have provided

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>UploadDrawingServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>UploadDrawingServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UploadDrawingServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/UploadDrawingServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And at servlet class its receiving as---

```
public class UploadDrawingServlet extends HttpServlet{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

System.out.println("Here in servlet class");
String file = request.getParameter("data");
}   
}
```

Can anybody tell me how to impliment following using ajax request. 
or if this type of request is not possible.
Thank you////

Answer (score 1):

```
function dynamicUpload(){
  var formElement = $("[name='attachfileform']")[0];
  var fd = new FormData(formElement); 
  var fileInput = $("[name='attachfile']")[0];
  fd.append('file', fileInput.files[0] );

  console.log(fd);

  $.ajax({
    url: 'UploadDrawingServlet',
    data: fd,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
    }
 });
```

}

See http://jsfiddle.net/ajk7J/

Comment: What particularly does not work? FormData object is incorrect, or ajax post request isn't sent to server, or do you recieve incorrect response?

Comment: Make sure that url in $.ajax is correct. I doubt that UploadDrawingServlet is correct one.

Comment: It executes the function onclick event but does not process the servlet class where i am recieving the file for furthe processing. I have provided a mapping in web.xml and just have a receiving function in servlet . I will update my question with .xml and servlet.

Comment: Have updated my question .Its not producing any output at console too.

Comment: Well, unfortunately i'm not familiar with java and servlets so i can't help you with sever side, but it seems to me that you've entered wrog url. For example, if you'd have used ASP.net MVC, url should have looked like 'UploadDrawingServlet/service' or 'UploadDrawingServlet.asmx/service' in case of using Web Services. I'd expect it should be something simmilar in your case.

Comment: No , url is fine i have used similar kind of ajax requests using same url patern , the point is sending a multipart form file. Anyways thanks for help ////

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you